# Collapse two bent edges

Tags: modeling, edges

Is there a way for me to mesh the edge 2 onto the edge 1? I can't manage to move the edge 2 with the proportional editing to match the first one

Thank you!

[image]

[Made a video to make it a little bit more visible](https://youtu.be/rwAyvVmtYXw)

Comment: you could use the Bridge Edge Loop tool but it's hard to understand the topology with your image

Answer (score 0):

(opinion: It is simpler to model the main parts of the helmet from one  sphere, because then you will keep all the points neatly aligned and the same number, which makes your job easier.)

However, if you know the vertices you want to snap together, select the meshes, and right click to **join** the two meshes.

Edge to edge, there is **bridge edge loops**, however I would suggest in edit mode, selecting the vertices you want to join and  **merge by distance**.  Unfortunately, it is always better when the meshes have the same number of points.

[image]